# C# WebClient Strange Characters

Tags: c#, python

I am trying to download this webpage  using C# WebClient..
Now it works perfectly with python urllib2 but with c# web client it gives these strange characters in the output file..

I have tried using Encoding with webclient class as well but it doesn't work at all..

```
public static string GetWebURL()
    {
        string url = "http://bet.hkjc.com";
        WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
        webClient.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
        string html = webClient.DownloadString(url);
        File.WriteAllText("page.html", html);
    }
```

this is the output with those strange characters

```
â€¹Ã¢Ã¥Â²QtÃ±wâ€°pUÃ°Ã±ÃµQuÃ²Ã±tVPÃ’Ã•Ã—7vÃ–Ã—w qÂHËœÃ¨*â€ž%Ã¦gâ€“dÃ¦Ã§%Ã¦Ã¨Ã«Â»Ãº)Ã™Ã±rÂ(N.ÃŠ,(Q(Â©,HÂµU*IÂ­(Ã‘ÃJ,Kâ€žË†*Ã™q)((â€U*TÆ’eâ€°E Â©yâ€°I9Â©Å½Ã‰Ã‰Â©Ã…Ã…ÃŽÃ¹y%EÃ¹9 Â¶iâ€°9Ã…Â©Ã– %â„¢i Xâ€h"(Ã‰-PÂ°U(ÃÃŒKÃ‰/Ã—Ã‹Ã‰ONÂ¹H/Â£(5MÂ¯Â¸4Â©Â¸Â¤HÃƒ\SlHuÂ°kPËœkPÂ¼Å¸Â£Â¯+PP/Lâ€˜ÂËœ4&ÂµÃ‚?MCI_ISÂ®+%?713Ã/17Â¨   Ã‰Ëœfd!Â¸   zJÅ¡Ãšâ€ PÂ«SÃ²â€œKsSÃ³JÃ´ &MA  VÂ¨Å¸KÃ²Ã´â€™RKâ€šs2ÃœÅ â‚¬ÂªÃ´2â€¹}Ã²Ã“Ã³Ã³445Â¡ÃŠÃ=Â­Wâ€ZÂâ€œËœÅ“ t|zj^jQbN<Ã˜1zâ€°Ã…Ã¶9â€°yÃ©Â¶Â©yJ_ÂP-Ë†Ã”Å¡Å“chË†eÂ¦â€š Âµ\H&[Ã—rÃ™Ã¨Câ€™â‚¬0ÂJ%Ã â€ž Ã·â€šÃ¼Ã¼P9UdÂ¦MÃÃÃ”ÃŒÃ˜ÃˆÃ–MÃ—ÃÃˆ25Â² Ã·Ã´Â³VÂ·â€ (ÃŽM-JOM
```

What should I do to see the html that is being send?

Comment: or this: http://bet.hkjc.com/racing/pages/odds_wp.aspx?date=09-06-2016&venue=HV&lang=en

Comment: Please show the same effort in writing your question that you'd expect someone to put in answering the question. Maybe some code of how you're "downloading" the page. Example of the strange characters and so on.

Comment: That's definitely not UTF8 - the site looks to be Chinese and UTF8 doesn't support it.Propably Unicode should work for you

Comment: I have tried that as well.. text just gets converted to unciode text but still not human readable

Comment: @Peter4499 [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) is an encoding to support all characters of Unicode which includes Chinese characters. The stream was compressed, it was not related to encoding.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking at a compressed byte stream. You can tell by inspecting the headers of the http response, for example with [curl](https://curl.haxx.se/):

`curl -X HEAD -i http://bet.hkjc.com/`

but the Developer Console of your browser will reveal the same:

> ```
> HTTP/1.1 200 OK
> Cache-Control: public, max-age=120, must-revalidate
> Content-Length: 3615
> Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
> Content-Encoding: gzip
> Expires: Wed, 29 Jun 2016 08:01:06 GMT
> Vary: Accept-Encoding
> Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.0
> X-AspNet-Version: 2.0.50727
> X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
> Date: Wed, 29 Jun 2016 08:00:14 GMT
> Via: 1.1 stjbwbwa52
> Accept-Ranges: bytes
> ```

Notice the `Content-Encoding:` to say *gzip*. This means the result you just got is compressed with the gzip algorithm. The standard WebClient can't handle that but with an simple subclass the WebClient can do new tricks:

```
public class DecompressWebClient:WebClient
{
    // moved common logic here
    public DecompressWebClient()
    {
        this.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
    }

    // This is the factory to create the webrequest
    protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri address)
    {
        // get the default one
        var request = base.GetWebRequest(address);
        // see if it is a HttpWebRequest
        var httpReq = request as HttpWebRequest;
        if (httpReq != null)
        {
            // add extra capabilities, like decompression
            httpReq.AutomaticDecompression =  DecompressionMethods.GZip;
        }
        return request;
    }
}
```

On the `HttpWebRequest` there exists a property [`AutomaticDecompression`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.automaticdecompression(v=vs.110).aspx) that, when set to true, will take care of the decompression for us.

When you put the Subclassed WebClient to use your code will look like:

```
string url = "http://bet.hkjc.com";
using(WebClient webClient = new DecompressWebClient())
{
    string html = webClient.DownloadString(url);
    File.WriteAllText("page.html", html);
}
```

The encoding UTF8 is correct, as you can also see in the header for the `Content-Type` setting.

The top of the html file will look like this:

> ```
> <html>
> <head>
>   <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7; IE=EmulateIE10"/>
>   <meta name="application-name" content="香港賽馬會"/>
>   <title>香港賽馬會</title>
> ```